# Select lines from stream whose first 4 characters are a number greatern than ...?

Tags: bash, grep

How can I select lines from a stream, such that the the first 4 characters represent a number greater than some other fixed value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output_cmd | awk 'substr($1,1,4)+0 > 9950'
```

will print a value if the first 4 characters are digits and are greater than 9950.
This pipes output into awk.